# How to mute notifications for some time in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background-process, flutter-local-notification

I am using **flutter_local_notifications** to display a notification for every prayer. But in app there is feature to mute notifications for "2 Hours", "5 Hours", etc. Just like in whatsapp we can mute some body chat for "8 Hours". So if user selects any duration let's be 5 hours. So the notification stops for next 5 hours. And automatically resumes after 5 Hours. This can be easily achieved if app is running in foreground. But if app is in terminated state. To achieve this is difficult task. I am using **background_fetch**. But don't know exactly how to achieve this.